# Forming a differential equation using word problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem

I'm not very good at forming differential equations by word problems so I need some help with this question:

A curve passing through the point (1,1) has the property that the perpendicular distance of the origin from the normal at any point P of the curve is equal to the distance of P from the x-axis. Determine the equation of the curve.

Comment: Give it a shot. What formula do you come up with?

Comment: Think about orthagonal trajectories.

Comment: I get 1= -(1/f'(1))+c given that the normal has the slope -1/f(x) at any point x. Then I substitute for c in the equation y=-1/f(x)+c . Post this, I find the distance from the orgin, and end up with (f'(x)^2)=(1+(f'(x))^2)/(1+(1/f'(1))^2